# Setup JPA Console in Intellij using Spring

Tags: spring, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm trying to get the JPA console working in Intellij. I have added JPA to the project under facets. However, IDE is asking for a persistence.xml. I'm using Annotated Spring and don't have any direct mapping files. Anyone configured this before, and can help me? Thanks

Further information:

Without adding JavaEE stuff - I don't need this.
File->Project Structure - Under modules: add JPA to a single module. Do not add persistence.xml or orm.xml

Under facets: Add JPA. Leave XML config blank. Leave JPA Provider blank

View -> Tool windows -> Persistence

You will see the module name and the EntityManager as configured under your SpringContext.xml. On my system I have these properties referenced in this SpringContext.xml

```
# jdbc.X
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql:///someThing
jdbc.user=postgres
jdbc.pass=postgres

# hibernate.X
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

I then select in my Persistence window (in which I can now see all entities) - click console button. Select JPA console. This will get me the error outlined here {yes, I'm using Postgres}

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206186929-JPA-Console-without-persistence-xml

Note the two "TTs-" PostgreSQL9Dialectt

Further further information:

Wierd. If I move the dialect into the actual xml config

```
 <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
           <!--<prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>-->
        </props>
    </property>

[2017-01-04 13:03:46] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
at com.intellij.jpa.remote.impl.RemoteQueryImpl$1.getResultList(RemoteQueryImpl.java:92)
at com.intellij.jpa.remote.impl.QueryResultImpl.ensureInitialized(QueryResultImpl.java:113)
at com.intellij.jpa.remote.impl.QueryResultImpl.getColumnInfos(QueryResultImpl.java:30)
at com.intellij.jpa.remote.impl.RemoteQueryResultImpl.getColumnInfos(RemoteQueryResultImpl.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: I'm working without `persistence.xml` , too, and for me, it works. Did you assign a datasource (within IntelliJ) to the project?

Comment: Hi Jim. Yeah. I added a datasource, and can run SQL queries from inside it. But I can't seem to get up a JPA QL window though.I add JPA under "project settings". It only offers me a chance to specify a persistence.xml or an orm.xml, neither of which I use. Thanks

Comment: Do you use the Community Edition or Uktimate?

Comment: What do you mean by JPA console? I have a tool window named "Java Enterprise" which shows me Persistence => moduleName => Entities. For that to work I just need a JPA facet on the module that has the entities - I have no persistence.xml, the EntityManagerFactory is configured using Spring, but the tool window works even without a Spring facet.

Comment: The JPA Console is a place to test your JPA QL queries. The part Klaus is talking about is easy to setup and work, just adding JPA facets seems to work. But the JPA Console is completely different and so far the only solutions I see is to make up an unnecessary and bogus persistence.xml just to placate IntelliJ

Comment: @user1567291 - I am new to Intelij Idea. Can you please show the process to add JPA facets and JPQL Console window?